# Closest value different files, with different number of lines and other conditions ( bash awk other)

Tags: bash, awk, sed, gawk

I have to revive and [old question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29827630/match-closest-value-from-two-different-files-and-print-specific-columns) with a modification for long files.

I have the age of two stars in two files (File1 and File2). The column of the age of the stars is $1 and the rest of the columns up to $13 are information that I need to print at the end.

I am trying to find an age in which the stars have the same age or the closest age. Since the files are too large (~25000 lines) I don't want to search in the whole array, for speed issues.
Also, they could have a big difference in number of lines (let say ~10000 in some cases)

I am not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem, but in a lack of a better one, this is my idea. (If you have a faster and more efficient method, please do it)

All the values are with 12 decimals of precision. And for now I am only concern in the first column (where the age is).

And I need different loops.

Let's use this value from file 1:

```
2.326062371284e+05
```

First the routine should search in file2 all the matches that contain

```
2.3260e+05
```

(This loop probably will search in the whole array, but if there is a way to stop the search as soon it reaches 2.3261 then it will save some time)

If it finds just one, then the output should be that value.

Usually, it will find several lines, maybe even up to 1000. It this is the case, it should search again against

```
2.32606e+05
```

between the lines founded before. (It is a nested loop I think)
Then the number of matches will decrease up to ~200

At that moment, the routine should search the best difference with certain tolerance X between

```
2.326062371284e+05
```

and all these 200 lines.

This way having these files

File1

```
1.833800650355e+05 col2f1 col3f1 col4f1
1.959443501406e+05 col2f1 col3f1 col4f1
2.085086352458e+05 col2f1 col3f1 col4f1
2.210729203510e+05 col2f1 col3f1 col4f1
2.326062371284e+05 col2f1 col3f1 col4f1
2.441395539059e+05 col2f1 col3f1 col4f1
2.556728706833e+05 col2f1 col3f1 col4f1
```

File2

```
2.210729203510e+05 col2f2 col3f2 col4f2
2.354895663228e+05 col2f2 col3f2 col4f2
2.499062122946e+05 col2f2 col3f2 col4f2
2.643228582664e+05 col2f2 col3f2 col4f2
2.787395042382e+05 col2f2 col3f2 col4f2
2.921130362004e+05 col2f2 col3f2 col4f2
3.054865681626e+05 col2f2 col3f2 col4f2
```

Output File3 (with tolerance 3000)

```
2.210729203510e+05 2.210729203510e+05 col2f1 col2f2 col4f1 col3f2
2.326062371284e+05 2.354895663228e+05 col2f1 col2f2 col4f1 col3f2
```

Important condition:

The output shouldn't contain repeated lines (the star 1 can't have at a fixed age, different ages for the star 2, just the closest one.

How would you solve this?

super thanks!

ps: I've change completely the question, since it was showed to me that my reasoning had some errors. Thanks!

Comment: Is heres a max tolerance ? (i.e, if we find a row wich diffrence is under X, stop there even if it's not exactly the closest one ?)

Comment: I think there should be a tolerance, I am not sure how to define it. It should not find an answer if the difference between the best closest value is too big. (what is big? 10 yr. The time column is in years).

Comment: When you say `the nearest 100 rows (up and down)` - does that mean 100 rows before plus 100 after, or 50 before plus 50 after? If the current line is 10 from the start does that mean the 10 lines before and 50 (or 100) after or the 10 lines before and 90 after or something else? Basically, edit your question to explain precisely what you mean by that statement, with examples. Also, to make it easy for us to test against, edit your question to reduce the size of the files to 10 or less lines and show THE expected output given that sample input if your window is, say, 4 lines instead of 100.

Comment: If the `NR` column isn't present in your input, don't include it in the example. We can count. Ditto for the first 2 lines. Make your files TESTABLE - we don't want to have to edit your files and guess at what rows and/or columns we need to remove to create your real input format - just post your real input and output format.

Comment: Thanks, I just want to make it the easiest way possible I can modify specifically for my files, but if you think is better the original input I can do it.

Comment: But, I cannot make it fully testable without adding more lines, and the position also matters even when I don't have it in my files. That is why is better this way if you agree.

Comment: Certainly don't add anything that is not present in your real files. After that, reduce the example you post to the smallest possible testable example that is truly representative of your real data and a solution for which you are confident you can enhance as necessary to apply to your real files. If it's just field 1 vs field 27 and/or 10 lines vs 1000 lines then that should be trivial for you to deal with. With what you currently have posted we'd have to write useless code to skip the first 2 lines and the first column - a complete waste of time that obfuscates the solution.

Comment: @Tensibai, is it clearer now?

Comment: @Nikko yes, sorry, been busy whole day and I did not had time to tackle it

Comment: no need to apologize =) I appreciate that all of you take time to help others. 
By the way I am modifying the question completely. Since due to the questions and doubts, I've found some problems with my reasoning.

Comment: @EdMorton I've updated the question maybe now is clearer why I need some conditions. Thanks!

Comment: It's usually better to ask a new question as a new question.

Comment: @choroba you are right. Sorry. :/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not an awk solution, comes a time when other solutions are great too, so here is an answer using [R](https://www.r-project.org/)

New answer with different datas, not reading from file this time to bake an example:

```
# Sample data for code, use fread to read from file and setnames to name the colmumns accordingly
set.seed(123)
data <- data.table(age=runif(20)*1e6,name=sample(state.name,20),sat=sample(mtcars$cyl,20),dens=sample(DNase$density,20))
data2 <- data.table(age=runif(10)*1e6,name=sample(state.name,10),sat=sample(mtcars$cyl,10),dens=sample(DNase$density,10))

setkey(data,'age') # Set the key for joining to the age column
setkey(data2,'age') # Set the key for joining to the age column

# get the result
result=data[ # To get the whole datas from file 1 and file 2 at end
         data2[ 
           data, # Search for each star of list 1
           .SD, # return columns of file 2
           roll='nearest',by=.EACHI, # Join on each line (left join) and find nearest value
          .SDcols=c('age','name','dens')]
       ][!duplicated(age) & abs(i.age - age) < 1e3,.SD,.SDcols=c('age','i.age','name','i.name','dens','i.dens') ] # filter duplicates in first file and on difference
# Write results to a file (change separator for wish):
write.table(format(result,digits=15,scientific=TRUE),"c:/test.txt",sep=" ")
```

---

Code:

```
# A nice package to have, install.packages('data.table') if it's no present
library(data.table)
# Read the data (the text can be file names)
stars1 <- fread("1.833800650355e+05
1.959443501406e+05
2.085086352458e+05
2.210729203510e+05
2.326062371284e+05
2.441395539059e+05
2.556728706833e+05")

stars2 <- fread("2.210729203510e+05
2.354895663228e+05
2.499062122946e+05
2.643228582664e+05
2.787395042382e+05
2.921130362004e+05
3.054865681626e+05")

# Name the columns (not needed if the file has a header)
colnames(stars1) <- "age"
colnames(stars2) <- "age"

# Key the data tables (for a fast join with binary search later)
setkey(stars1,'age')
setkey(stars2,'age')

# Get the result (more datils below on what is happening here :))
result=stars2[ stars1, age, roll="nearest", by=.EACHI]

# Rename the columns so we acn filter whole result
setnames(result,make.unique(names(result)))

# Final filter on difference
result[abs(age.1 - age) < 3e3]
```

So the interesting parts are the first 'join' on the two stars ages list, searching for each in stars1 the nearest in stars2.

This give (after column renaming):

```
> result
        age    age.1
1: 183380.1 221072.9
2: 195944.4 221072.9
3: 208508.6 221072.9
4: 221072.9 221072.9
5: 232606.2 235489.6
6: 244139.6 249906.2
7: 255672.9 249906.2
```

Now we have the nearest for each, filter those close enough (on absolute difference above 3 000 here):

```
> result[abs(age.1 - age) < 3e3]
        age    age.1
1: 221072.9 221072.9
2: 232606.2 235489.6
```

Comment: Thanks @Tensibai, installing R and trying to run the code.

Comment: Take care of comments, specially the first one to install the package :) I'm unsure of what you want to do at end, but I've the feeling R could be an interresting tool for you if you wish to graph the stars according to their relative distance or to make some statistical analysis on the data

Comment: I reckon I wanted to learn R this year...but sadly I haven't found the time. I've just installed, and tryed to install the package, I get this: Warning message:
package ‘data.table’ is not available (for R version 3.2.3) 
And guess what version I have (3.2.3).

Comment: I'm on ubuntu 14.04. Fixed, I've change the mirror and it works. The code compiles and work super with the example. Now I'll try with the real files.

Comment: Can you please modify it to save the result into a file? @Tensibai

Comment: I think it is perfect! thanks to everyone! ( and so fast!)

Comment: as Ed morton predicted, it would be better to say the exact problem. How can I print the specific columns of file1 and file2 also in result? @Tensibai

Comment: I meant, the thing is file1 and file2  have about 20 columns. The firstone is time and the other information about the star, I want to print column, 2,5,8,11 of file1 and file2 for each row in result. for example. Enjoy lunch!

Comment: So it is not as simple as I thought. The things is the whole point of get this close age is to compare variables from the stars at that age, that information is in the other columns, and for some calculation I need to use both columns to calculate another variable...

Comment: and also, as I  wrote in the question, how can I get rid off the repeated lines, and as soon a set the tolerance >0 it finds (probably obviously) more than one match, how can I say that then it should choose the best difference between those lines?. Although this has less priority I could work with tolerance = 0. Although the number of lines decreases almost to the half.

Comment: @Nikko updated the answer with another example and multiples columns, syntax is a little different but I hope I commented enough on what does what.

Comment: Thank you very much! Super nice answer, sorry for all the changes. I think this routine also work, I am trying to assign the name to the columns as you suggest I am learning how, I have no idea about R. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, last hour I couldn't find how. Can you please tell me how to do this: "use fread to read from file and setnames to name the colmumns accordingly"
I've tried what I've read searching how to do that, but without success.. I'm sure is just one line. =/

Comment: @Nikko See the first code (under the break bar) `data <-fread('file1'); setnames(data,c('age','col2f1','col3f1',...))`

Comment: ok perfect. It works, I've tried to obtain the results in scientific notation, but is not working. I've used "options( digits = 15 )" and "result2= format(result, scientific=TRUE);" which worked for me in the 1 column example. But when I do this, it is written everything in one column )

Comment: Both ways are working with the same output, just one column in test.txt  Why is that?

Comment: Ahh perfect, I thought it was my fault. if I change .SDcols=1,4 it will print just those two columns right?

Comment: @Nikko I've updated with your desired output from my example, names can be replaced by index position. Hope this gives a proper insight to extend it :)

Comment: @Nikko side note, I think we should clean up comments above, they are useless now IMO.

Comment: Excellent, everything is working as I wanted. thanks for the patience!.

Comment: @Nikko you're welcome. I hope your learned enough to write a good question at first try next time ;) (We're all happy to help people showing efforts to learn by trying and accepting criticism to improve ;))

Comment: Oh yes I've learned a lot! thanks! (I need to keep learning I guess because I have a lot of questions, probably I'll make new ones =) ) thanks again.

Comment: I'm getting this: rror in vecseq(f__, len__, if (allow.cartesian || notjoin || !anyDuplicated(f__,  : 
  Join results in 106284 rows; more than 80108 = nrow(x)+nrow(i). Check for duplicate key values in i each of which join to the same group in x over and over again. If that's ok, try by=.EACHI to run j for each group to avoid the large allocation. If you are sure you wish to proceed, rerun with allow.cartesian=TRUE. Otherwise, please search for this error message in the FAQ, Wiki, Stack Overflow and datatable-help for advice.
Calls: [ -> [.data.table -> vecseq
Execution halted

Comment: how can I fix it? (I already try with allow.cartesian=TRUE, but nothing happens =/)

Comment: @Nikko oops, sorry. Well this sounds like a full new Q, gettign why it hangs, reading code in comments is awfull, can you post a new question and set the link here  please ?

Answer (score 2):

Perl to the rescue. This should be very fast, as it does a binary search in the given range.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw{ say };

use List::Util qw{ max min };
use constant { SIZE      => 100,
               TOLERANCE => 3000,
           };


my @times2;
open my $F2, '<', 'file2' or die $!;
while (<$F2>) {
    chomp;
    push @times2, $_;
}

my $num = 0;
open my $F1, '<', 'file1' or die $!;
while (my $time = <$F1>) {
    chomp $time;

    my $from = max(0, $num - SIZE);
    my $to   = min($#times2, $num + SIZE);
    my $between;
    while (1) {
        $between = int(($from + $to) / 2);

        if ($time < $times2[$between] && $to != $between) {
            $to = $between;

        } elsif ($time > $times2[$between] && $from != $between) {
            $from = $between;

        } else {
            last
        }
    }
    $num++;
    if ($from != $to) {
        my $f = $time - $times2[$from];
        my $t = $times2[$to] - $time;
        $between = ($f > $t) ? $to : $from;
    }
    say "$time $times2[$between]" if TOLERANCE >= abs $times2[$between] - $time;
}
```

Comment: I've compile but I get this: 
Missing right curly or square bracket at closest.pl line 37, at end of line
syntax error at closest.pl line 37, at EOF
Execution of closest.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
   After I've added the right curly at line 37 I get this. 
    Global symbol "$nr" requires explicit package name at closest.pl line     38.
Global symbol "$time" requires explicit package name at closest.pl line 38.
Global symbol "$between" requires explicit package name at closest.pl line 38.
Execution of closest.pl aborted due to compilation errors.

Comment: It works for me. What Perl version do you have? `perl -v`. Have you noticed there's a scrollbar on the right?

Comment: without or with the right curly ? version: (v5.18.2)

Comment: @Nikko: As posted here. Nothing is missing (you probably didn't copy the closing right curly bracket, and added it manually to a wrong position).

Comment: I've updated the question. In principle it is working, but I am expecting just two lines of output. Can you fix it?

Comment: @Nikko: I don't understand the question now. Why are there only two lines in the output?

Comment: I think just to adding a tolerance to your code, it should work. Just two lines because they are the only ones that fulfill the tolerance condition.

Comment: Thanks! It is working with the example, but when I check with a larger file it doesn't display the correct output. 
I think the lines with the same value (so the difference is 0) are not being displayed ,except for the first nr.

Comment: and when I try with the real file it says repeatedly this:
Use of uninitialized value in numeric gt (>) at closest.pl line 33, <$F1> line 21618.

Comment: @Nikko: Can you show an input line that produces the warning?

Comment: http://www.filedropper.com/file1_2 and http://www.filedropper.com/file2_1 are the original files. I don't know perl too much. But I am sure with those files you will get something.

Comment: I'm not getting any files from the links.

Comment: Weird I've tested them, another host: http://www.filehosting.org/file/details/541924/bothfiles.zip

Comment: I'm not giving my email address to anyone.

Comment: http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=07762346186856365156

no email needed.

Comment: The two files don't have the same number of lines. The difference is about 9000, which is more than the "SIZE". Setting SIZE to 8643 is enough.

Comment: exactly! and the files are like this (I should've said that in the example.)

Comment: @Nikko: It doesn't make any sense. What line from file2 should I use to match line number 29320 from file1?

Comment: I know what is the problem. I wasn't aware of the big difference of the lines for the example... At the end is simple, it should be compared with the lasts lines from file 2 ... (what matters more is the time, than the NR, the closer the better.)

Comment: I think your routines is almost perfect. But for example it has repeated values that shouldn't exist.

Comment: @Nikko: Where is that stated in the question?

Comment: It is not. I am updating the better I can now.

Comment: Maybe just adding `$num = $between;` before the `say` line helps?

Comment: I think it didn't. I am updating the question without talking in general now, maybe is clearer. Why I need some conditions.

Comment: I think is better instead of searching using NR, will be for example if the value I am searching is 4.071420520520e+06 search

Comment: it is basically a new question, but thanks to you I found a problem in my logic. I am fixing it now. I think is better to do a double loop. For example if I am searching the closest to 4.071420520520e+06 first it has to search the closest value to 4.0714 but check if they are too many of them. Let's say the routine found 1000 lines that match that.

Comment: Then search again but against 4.07142 and if the number of lines found is less than some value (let's say 100) then search between those lines the closest age under some tolerance (3000 years) if the tolerance is satisfied then again should choose the closest between them.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102929/discussion-between-nikko-and-choroba).